# C# Working with mulitcolumn list

Tags: c#, sql

I've created a multicolumn list (lstItems) that I want to use for lookups so I don't have to do repeated data queries and I can't figure out how to reference the items/cells.  If an alternate structure would be better/easier, I'm open to suggestions, but this is what I've got so far.

I can query the OLEDB table and populate lstItems but not sure how to reference the elements/cells.  As a test I populated listbox1 from the query.  Then after building lstItems I echoed back the contents, no problem.  Now I need to do two things.

1. Populate listbox1 with one of the columns from lstItems instead of directly from the query.
2. Later, be able to query lstItems so when "nameValue" = the second column nameValue, return the corresponding ID.

.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "select ID, Name from table;
OleDbDataReader sqlRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

// Create a Name/Value list
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lstItems = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
int j = 0;

while (sqlRead.Read())
{
//Populate listbox1 directly from query
  string nm= Convert.ToString(sqlRead["Name"]);
  listBox1.Items.Add(nm);  

// Create the multicolumn list
  lstItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>
    (Convert.ToString(sqlRead["ID"]), Convert.ToString(sqlRead["Name"])));   
// Echo out to insure the list has the proper values
  MessageBox.Show("Show List: " +lstItems [j].ToString());
  j++;
}
```

Comment: Well, if it were me, I'd use a data adapter, fill a data table, then just bind the listbox to that. Is this a asp.net listbox, or a forms listbox? Also, if you use data binding, you don't need to look up the id for the selected item, it's right there for you to use.

Comment: This is a forms listbox (not asp.net)  I'm using the listboxes as selections, i.e. the user makes a selection from Listbox1 and it's moved to Listbox2 ... Consequently I don't think I can use Data Binding.

Comment: Sure you can. Do they need to move items back from listbox 2 to listbox 1? Also, when they move it from L1 to L2, should it disappear from L1?

Comment: Yes & Yes.  The user selects from Listbox1, the item is removed from box1 & added to box2.  In box2 they can re-sequence the items (move up or down), order is important.  They can also remove items from box2 and it gets added back to box1, which is maintained in alphabetical order.  When I tried doing this with data binding I got errors.  I followed the suggestions here and went with a data table ... this solved my problem ... I build the table with ID & Name, then populate box1 with name, then as the user works with box2 I collect the ID in sequence.

Comment: You can do that with data binding, but you don't need to, and it probably is easier without it when moving things back and forth like that. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use DataTables for this sort of thing personally. I will then reference the table instead of the database when I need the data for lookups:

```
sqlRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
var dt = new DataTable();
for (var i = 0; i < sqlRead.FieldCount; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(sqlRead.GetName(i), typeof(string));
}

while (sqlRead.Read())
{
    var row = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (var i = 0; sqlRead.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var val = sqlRead[i].ToString();
        row[i] = val;
    }

}
sqlRead.Close();
```

OR:

```
// Connection object is the second parameter
using (var a = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID, Name from table", c)) 
{
    var t = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(t);
}
```

Then you can reference the DataTable for data!

Comment: Wouldn't data adapter fill be easier if you wanted a datatable?

Comment: Same thing but long hand version

Answer (score 0):

Example binding for winforms

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable(); 
    using (SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select ProductID, ProductName from Product", oSqlConnection))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oSqlCommand))
            {
                adapter.Fill(oDataTable);
            }
        }
    }
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "ProductID";
    listBox1.DataSource = oDataTable;

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedRow["ProductId"].ToString());

}
```